# Unable to run eas commands

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, eas

I'm having issues with eas commands since I've updated the eas-cli (0.59.0 and higher)

Anytime I try to run an eas command I get the following message:

[image]

Would anyone be able to help please?

expo version: 6.0.2

expo sdk: 46

eas works fine for version 0.58.0, which is what I'm using in the meantime